# Binding Source doesn't work on column names with two or more words in DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, filter, bindingsource

```
Dim bagentdata As New BindingSource
Dim myCommand As New MySqlCommand
Dim myAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
Dim myData As New DataTable
Dim SQL As String

Private Sub frmAgent_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Try
        'conn.Open()
        ConnectDatabase()
        SQL = ""
        SQL = "SELECT ID, Name `Agent Name`, Address, Pincode, ContactNo, AltContactNo, SelfIPType, SelfIPRef, SelfIPA, SelfIPP, " & _
                            "IsIPOPD, IPOPDType, IPOPDValue, IsActive, CreatedBy, CreatedOn FROM tblagentmaster"

        myCommand.Connection = Conn
        myCommand.CommandText = SQL

        myAdapter.SelectCommand = myCommand
        myData.Clear()
        myAdapter.Fill(myData)

        Me.AgentDataView.DataSource = myData
        Me.AgentDataView.DefaultCellStyle.Font = New Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold)
        AgentDataView.ReadOnly = True
        CloseDatabase()
    Catch myerror As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show("Error: " & myerror.Message)
    End Try
    Clear.PerformClick()
End Sub

Private Sub Search_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Search.TextChanged
        bagentdata.DataSource = myData
        AgentDataView.DataSource = bagentdata
        bagentdata.Filter = "[Agent Name] Like '%" & Search.Text & "%' " & _
                            " OR ContactNo = " & Val(Search.Text) & " OR ID = " & Val(Search.Text)
        If Search.Text = "" Then
            Clear.PerformClick()
        End If
End Sub
```

Filter by Agent Name is not working, please anyone need help on this. Filter by ID or Contactno is working fine. I have a similar kind of code in another form, there it's working fine.

Edit: Even if I change the SQL = "SELECT ID, Name, Address, Pincode, ContactNo, AltContactNo, SelfIPType, SelfIPRef, SelfIPA, SelfIPP, IsIPOPD, IPOPDType, IPOPDValue, IsActive, CreatedBy, CreatedOn FROM tblagentmaster"
and Filter Text as bagentdata.Filter = "Name Like '%" & Search.Text & "%' " then also Filter By Name not working.
Below adding another Sample code where the Filter is working perfectly:

```
Sub ClearAll(rindex As Integer)
        Try
            ConnectDatabase()
            SQL = ""
            SQL = "SELECT BillNo as BillNO, date(CaseCreatedOn) as 'Booked On', PatientName as `Patient Name` , UHID, PatientAge as Age, PatientSex as Gender FROM tblbooking " & _
                "where BillNo in (SELECT DISTINCT BillNo FROM tblbookingdetails WHERE ItemStatus in (7,8)) ORDER BY 'Booked On', BillNO"

            myCommand.Connection = Conn
            myCommand.CommandText = SQL

            myAdapter.SelectCommand = myCommand
            myData.Clear()
            myAdapter.Fill(myData)

            allbilldtv.DataSource = myData
            CloseDatabase()
        Catch myerror As MySqlException
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " & myerror.Message)
        End Try
        Try
            allbilldtv.CurrentCell = allbilldtv.Rows(rindex).Cells(0)
            allbilldtv_CellClick(Nothing, Nothing)
        Catch err As ArgumentOutOfRangeException
            MessageBox.Show("Report Generate Queue All Cleared...!!!", "©2022-25 Healeon™ - All Rights Reserved®", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        End Try
    End Sub
Private Sub CommonSearch_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CommonSearch.TextChanged
        Try
            allbilldata.DataSource = myData
            allbilldtv.DataSource = allbilldata
            allbilldata.Filter = "[Patient Name] Like '%" & CommonSearch.Text.ToUpper & "%' OR BillNO = " & Val(CommonSearch.Text)

            If CommonSearch.Text = "" Then
                ClearAll(0)
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: The column name in your SQL statement doesn't look right, it should read `SELECT ID, [Agent Name] ...`

Comment: The name of a Column should not contain spaces. The Caption / Header / Description and Name are different things.

Comment: You need to define "not working" and provide specific examples that we can test for ourselves.

Comment: user18387401 -- "not working" as if datagrid is not getting filtered, it remains same.

Comment: Hel O'Ween -- The column name in SQL statement, I have tried with 'Agent Name', [Agent Name], but my issue with filter remain unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation for BindingSource.Filter ([here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.filter#remarks)):

> If the underlying data source is a DataSet, DataTable, or DataView,
> you can specify Boolean expressions using the syntax documented for
> the DataColumn.Expression property.

Then according to the documentation for DataColumn.Expression ([here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression#expression-syntax)):

> When you create an expression, use the ColumnName property to refer to
> columns.

I would suggest doing this following:

1. Setup a breakpoint when filling the DataTable's data
2. Step over (F10 shortcut key) to the next line
3. Inspect the Columns property of the DataTable

What I suspect is happening is that the Fill method is massaging the column name to conform to proper naming convention, e.g. *"Agent Name"* becomes *"AgentName"*. Once you have the actual name of the DataColumn, use it in your filter.

Comment: I have checked the actual name of the DataColumn, and it is "Agent Name"